# Regualr expression to check ip address with short mask

Tags: php, validation, ip-address

I want to validate an IP address with mask, like this: `192.168.32.4/24` but I only found how to validate an IP without the mask: `192.168.32.4`

This is my code:

```
$target = "192.168.34.12";

if (preg_match("/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/", $target)) {
    echo "correct";
} else {
    echo "incorrect";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**[Solved]**

```
$target = "192.168.34.12/24";
$regex = "/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])$/";

if (preg_match($regex, $target)) {
    echo "correct";
} else {
    echo "incorrect";
}
```

Comment: What if you `explode` at `/` and then validate the IP and the mask separately?

Comment: This is not I'm looking for, I want to validate the entire expression, not only the IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual regex is :

```
$regex = "/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/";
```

and it recognizes an IP like this : 192.168.0.150

If you want to recognize IP with mask (like 192.168.32.4/24) do this regex :

```
$regex = "/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])$/";
```

In this last regex I just add `\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])`. The `\` is used to espace the `/`. Otherwise the regex would believe it's the end of itself. The last part `([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])` is to accept mask from 1 to 24 only.

And finally your code would be like this :

```
$target = "192.168.34.12/24";
$regex = "/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])$/";

if (preg_match($regex, $target)) {
    echo "correct";
} else {
    echo "incorrect";
}
```

PS : If you want to test your regex, this site is very cool : https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you! This works, but the mask is from 1 to 24.

Comment: Oh ok, so I changed the regex, because the old one accepted mask from 0 to 999. Now the regex accpets mask from 1 to 24, like you said. I edited the answer

Comment: Yeah my bad I didn't put the / at the beginning and the end of the regex. It should works now, I edited again the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$target = "192.168.34.123";


if (preg_match("/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/",$target)) {
    echo "correct";
} else {
    echo "incorrect";
}
```

Comment: This allows IP's like this: 777.168.34.123

Comment: May this will help you : preg_match("/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/",$target) OR you can use PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_IP . Example: "filter_var($target, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)"